# error in eclipse "Type Unable to resolve target 'android-3' "

Tags: android, eclipse

Imported a sample project , trying to run the app
but getting the errror "Type Unable to resolve target 'android-3'"
is this build path problem??

Comment: i am using eclipse juno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have this in your sdk API level-3. Download it or change target to other.

Comment: could you specify the path please.,i.e in which file manifest or properties??

Comment: Right click on project -> Properties -> Android

Comment: Had this problem, and I didn't have 3 installed. But I just went to Properties->Android based on the above suggestion and just checked the version of android I wanted to use and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is it's looking for an Android API of level 3 of which you either haven't downloaded or aren't targeting.

- Right click on your project and go to Properties->Android and select your API 3 Android version.  If you don't have this version, you can select whatever API level you like.  Hit apply and okay. Now right click on your project and go to Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the Android SDK API 3? As far as I know the error basically says that in the build path you configured it to use API 3 but you don't have it installled.

An alternative would be, if you have another API installed, juts to configure the project to use that API in the build path (backwards compatibility is given).

Answer (score 1):

The target api for the project has not been set. You need to set those from the android project properties.
Right click on project and select the properties Or select the project and press ALT + ENTER key.
A new properties window will open.
Then select Android in the properties window and set the required target API from the list.
Apply this settings and your problem will be solved.